# XRDP Session on Ubuntu missing dialog text

Tags: xrdp

I am RDPing into an Ubuntu machine using Windows Remote Desktop.  While it connects fine, after awhile, the UI dialog text mostly vanishes and stops appearing.  This includes anything across the toolbar up top, text on context menus from the dock, and my entire applications screen is just icons, no text.

This goes away if I logout, but often returns very quickly.

Any ideas?  This really negatively impacts functionality.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Installed XRDP using `sudo apt install xrdp`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you set up XRDP in Ubuntu. Did you install? If so how? Add all these [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1424184/edit).

Comment: sorry, didn't think about that.   I updated it just now.

Comment: Someone has written [a script to install xrdp](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18205) and tweak it to work as expected with Ubuntu. I can't tell you if it will help you or not. As always. you will have to decide if you want to download and run a script from the internet, and the risks it has.